# How should I translate RISC-V bytecode into WASM?

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, llvm, webassembly, riscv

For a project I'm working on, it would be useful to be able to run RISC-V assembly in the browser fast. From what I can tell, I think the fastest way to do this is to translate the RISC-V assembly/bytecode into WASM. My first question is, is there a faster or similarly fast way to run RISC-V in the browser? My second question is, are there any existing projects which do this translation? I've heard of projects like CheerpX which translates x86 into WASM, and I believe Qemu can translate RISC-V bytecode into native bytecode.

If tools exist for this then great, but if not then my next question is how should I go about implementing this myself? I just started learning about LLVM and what I'm thinking of doing is creating a RISC-V frontend for LLVM, so I can go `RISC-V -> LLVM-IR -> WASM -> native`. One advantage is I might get higher performance than if I tried translating directly to WASM myself: I believe some performance is lost whenever you translate from one IR to another, but I can use existing LLVM optimization passes to hopefully get performance similar to a high level language compiled through LLVM to WASM. Another advantage is more code reuse: if someone else (or me later) wants to translate RISC-V to native assembly, then they can use the same frontend. So my third question is, is this a good idea or would you do something different? I know assembly to LLVM is not the intended direction, but I feel like it might be a good move here?

Comment: Normally, we would call risc v code "machine code", and not "byte code".  However the best way to wasm would be to go straight from source code, rather than through in intermediary like machine code.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks for the clarification. For the project I'm working on the programs in question would start out as RISC-V assembly.

Comment: Then you'll need something that "decompiles" it back to something that can be compiled into WASM, such as LLVM-IR.  Standard toolchains don't come with such tools.  Or write WASM by hand, manually porting from the hand-written RISC-V asm source which you apparently have for some reason.